# Strange Cycles render artifact with some meshes starting with Blender 3.1, Windows 11

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, objects

****UPDATE:** I have added a link to an example of this issue; I think it may have originally been created in SketchUp. (As this is a 3rd-party creation, I have deliberately "broken" the object, but the artifact remains.)**

**[blend example](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/panel_artifact_debug.blend)**

I have some 3rd-party payware models that I purchased a year ago. They look fine when rendered in Cycles under Blender 3.0 and earlier, but render in 3.1 and later and the objects have these strange "zebra" line patterns.

The artifacts exist independently of the materials (changing or removing materials makes no difference), and sometimes it seems that the artifacts are "floating" above the meshes. I have never seen this before, and no matter what I try I cannot make the artifacts go away. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.4. Windows 11

[image]

Comment: First thing I would try is updating your graphics drivers.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks for the tip. It does look like a graphics issue, however, I have the latest graphics drivers installed: ZOTAC GeForce 8GB RTX 3060 Ti v528.02

Comment: As you've noted below... the topology is a nightmare :) . Double-faces everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [z fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). Basically, looks like there are double meshes, of double faces. Unfortunately, there is no easy fix, other than manually removing the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It does indeed look like Z-fighting. Interesting that for this mesh it only becomes an issue in Blender versions 3.1 and later. I passed this on to the creator who's still trying to figure it out.